# How to use groovy formal parameters in a properties file

Tags: groovy, properties

I have such a properties file:

```
envHost=http://some.host
api.host=${envHost}
backoffice.host=${envHost}
```

And when I get, e.g, api.host property from my properties file:

```
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getResource("/envs/someEnv.properties").toURI()))
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(input)
        println prop.'api.host'
```

I get `${envHost}` instead of `http://some.host`

How can I get value `http://some.host` from properties file using formal parameters therein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change to properties file to a config-slurper valid format:

```
envHost="http://some.host"
api.host=envHost
backoffice.host=envHost
```

You can then do:

```
def cfg = new ConfigSlurper().parse(getClass().getResource("/envs/someEnv.properties"))
println cfg.api.host
```

And it should work

Comment: How can I get property value? get() or getProperty() on ConfigObject return null or [:]

Comment: Assuming `"/envs/someEnv.properties"` exists in your classpath, you should just do dot properties (see above, I changed the example)

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks! What about if we have our property key like a variable? e.g. we have  String propertyKeyName = 'api.host'   then    cfg."${propertyKeyName}"     don't work, it returns [:]

Comment: Ahhh, then you need to split the key and walk through the values.  With Groovy 3 you can do:  `propertyNameKey.split('\\.').inject(cfg) { m, k -> m?[k] }`